# Why is my backend returning undefined for req.body?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

My stack: React frontend, SQL database, Express middleware.
I have values of a user's registration in state passed to backend here:

```js
handleSubmit = event => {
      event.preventDefault();
  
      const user = {
        name: this.state.name,
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password
      };
  
      axios.post(`${REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/api/users/register`, { user })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
          console.log(res.data);
        })
}
```

I have my server responding here:

```js
router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body)
    db.User.findOne({
        email: req.body.user.email
    }).then(user => {
        if(user) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                email: 'Email already exists'
            });
        }
        else {
            const newUser = new User({
                name: req.body.user.name,
                email: req.body.user.email,
                password: req.body.user.password
            });
            
            bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
                if(err) console.error('There was an error', err);
                else {
                    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
                        if(err) console.error('There was an error', err);
                        else {
                            user.password = hash;
                            user
                                .create()
                                .then(user => {
                                    res.json(user)
                                }); 
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I've logged the user being passed and the values read in my front end but my backend returns an empty object. I know I'm very junior but what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

your are using `const newUser` at creating object you have to do like this if you want to create new use

```
       const newUser = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
        });

     console.log(newUser)
```

`console.log(newUser)` thi will shows the user data which was created by you

Comment: Because I'm passing in the user from my frontend I'd need it to be req.body.user.name etc. But irregardless my req.body is returning empty.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up changing my code around a lot. But I think the issue with this is that I must use "body-parser" to pass JSON values to SQL. So if you're having a similar issue read about body-parser.

```js
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' })); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
     limit: '50mb',
     extended: true,
     parameterLimit: 50000
}));
```

Comment: What exactly did you do to fix your issue? Your Answer here is sort of vague.